# Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 in deployed code only (mvc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a MVC 5 application which is working fine in development environment. When I publish and deploy it in testing server (or any other , I get javascript error on login button click:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Below is screenshot of the error[image]

Please let me know if any other information is required from my side.

```
 $("#login-form").on('submit', function (event) {
        var Basic = new Object();
        Basic.UserName = $("#username").val();
        Basic.password = $("#password").val();
        Basic.RememberMe = $("#RememberMe").val();
        var timezone = jstz.determine();
        Basic.Continue = timezone.name();
        $("#loginerror").text("");
        var isValid = $(this).valid();
        if (isValid == false) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "@session.HostURL" + "/auth",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(Basic),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                window.location = "@session.HostURL";
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                if (data === null) {
                    $("#loginerror").text(textStatus + " HttpCode : " + xhr.status);
                } else {
                    $("#loginerror").text(data.ResponseStatus.Message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This error means that the response is not valid JSON. Without seeing your code or the response, we cannot help any further than that

Comment: Code works fine in development env. Let me add the code...

Comment: `async: false`. Yuk. There's almost never a good reason to use this. You're using callbacks correctly so it seems unnecessary. It will just lock the UI for the user, which is not user-friendly. Also some browsers have already deprecated this so it may stop working in future.

Comment: The issue is not with your JS (although `async: false` needs to be removed ASAP). The issue is on the server side that's generating the response. You need to use the console and check the responseText of the request.

Comment: It looks like maybe an OPTIONS request is failing. Is this a CORS request? Is the server configured to respond to OPTIONS requests?

Comment: Do you get an error if you put the JSON you receive (look at the response in the network-panel call) into a JSON validator?

Comment: Code deployed in same server was working fine in previous release. This release we did not change anything in Login, still facing this issue

Comment: @Aruna If it used to work, then clearly _something_ has changed. So you need to test and see where the difference was. Perhaps some unintended change occurred, or there's a regression due to something else. A server config change could also be involved. Check everything that was intended to be changed, and then everything that actually _was_ changed.

Comment: I tried to see in Network-panel call and I get error in the auth code of jquery.min.js and Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade. Does this mean anything?

Comment: what's the error exactly, in full?

Comment: The success function looks weird: what happens when you console.log the response?

Comment: I will check and post it

Comment: @frenchie it's not going to the success function by the looks of it. The error is in parseJSON which is only called by the error function. If you're saying it's weird to immediately redirect to another URL after completing an ajax request, I'd say yes, and makes me wonder OP is even bothering with ajax in this scenario - the server-side could just process the request and then redirect. I don't know but given this is an auth process, that also sounds potentially a bit more secure. But anyway what interests me from the screenshot is the seemingly failed OPTIONS preflight request just above.

Comment: @frenchie added it in the question edit

Comment: @Aruna so the ajax failed to execute at all. Again, check whether your server can serve pre-flight OPTIONS requests correctly. But also as I mentioned above, this is really quite a bad use-case for ajax. The point of ajax is to remove the need to refresh the page. But in the success case your code just refreshes/redirects the page anyway. So an ajax request in this context has no real solid purpose. Just get the server to redirect appropriately depending on whether authentication succeeded or not.

Comment: ok, I will check and update

Comment: What happens when you navigate to /auth just with the browser? I think it's the routing that's broken.

Comment: also I note that you said this problem is occurring on a test server, but yet the URLs shown in the screenshots say "localhost". Are you sure some setting (e.g. session.HostURL) is not still referring to the development machine's URL when it ought to refer to the test server's URL? Normally you don't even need to make this a config item, the application can do this for itself. If you're using MVC you should be using helper methods to construct your URLs for you anyway. It avoids bad routes and also this kind of hostname issue.

Comment: When I say /auth, it just says localhost refused to connect.and It is localhost as I am browsing in the same server

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes from the `error` handler in your `$.ajax` call, in fact the `xhr.responseText` is expected to be a JSON response but it came as a text string or `undefined` instead, so when you try to `parse` it in:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
```

It will throw this error.

You will need to check over this value if it's a valid JSON string before trying to parse it or just change the handler like this:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (data === null) {
                    $("#loginerror").text(textStatus + " HttpCode : " + xhr.status);
                } else {
                    $("#loginerror").text(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }
```

And as mentioned in comments, the `async: false,` is useless in this request.

Comment: Clearly the whole point of parseJSON is to parse text into JSON. If it's not JSON then yes obviously it will fail. But we don't know whether the response is intended to be JSON or not, because OP hasn't said. `dataType: "json"` implies it ought to be, even for errors. So removing parseJSON is not _necessarily_ the solution. Possibly the solution is to fix the dodgy server output. We don't really know for sure. Also as per the jQuery docs, since `dataType: "json"` was specified, there should be a `xhr.responseJSON` property also available which could be used without parsing the text version.

Comment: They are trying to write some `data.ResponseStatus.Message` into the DOM in some cases, which also suggests that JSON was the intended format for the error response.

Comment: Standard MVC errors will not be in JSON format. So unless the OP has changed that (not mentioned) than 'xhr.responseText' will not be valid JSON.

Comment: @ADyson Yes good point on that, but yes the main problem behind that is that the response is not `JSON`

Comment: @TSR if it's a JSONResult containing a modelstate then it might well be. Or again, the use of `$("#loginerror").text(data.ResponseStatus.Message);` suggests some custom JSON format is expected.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the string is undefined. It converts undefined to a string and tries to parse it, hence the 'u' at position 0.

Are you sure xhr has the property responseText? and it has a value?

Comment: @Aruna what is its value?

Comment: I will check and post it